# Can you use a virtual machine to performance test an application?

Tags: windows, testing, virtualization

I develop a desktop Windows application that is deployed onto a variety of client PCs, ranging from net-books to large workstations.  It would be useful to be able to performance test it on a low spec machine.  Is it possible to constrain the performance of a virtual machine so that it performance is like that of a low spec machine?

Update: my preferred VM technology is VMWare Workstation, in case that affects the answer.

Comment: Hello Sean, the possibility to constrain the specs of virtual machine depends on the solution you want to use. Could you tell us which software you want to make use of?

Comment: I have found it easier to just test it on real hardware. Windows version also matters.

Comment: You could also load a real machine, leaving fewer CPU cycles and I/O bandwidth to the app.

Comment: @Andreas - updated question to show VM technology.

Comment: @SeanKearon asked, because we have done something like this on vmware. Post the document we used as entry point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [VMware ESXi](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere/esxi-and-esx/index.html), yes (free version is fine) but not with Workstation - although if desired you can use Workstation 8 as a remote console for ESXi.

In addition to the Workstation features, ESXi provides [resource management](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/vsphere4/r40/vsp_40_resource_mgmt.pdf) so you can restrict the CPU available and control priority of disk access, network bandwidth and other system resources.

Answer (score 1):

To an extent yes, but it mught not be the same kind of slow a truly low powered machine would be. An example is that the host OS file cache could cause files to be loaded from RAM cache instead of spining the disk and this could cause the VM to outperform a real machine with the same RAM size with programs that does a lot of disk access.

Comment: So, am I right in reading this as it is not therefore possible to fully model the disk characteristics?  That is an issue as the host has a rapid SSD.

Answer (score 0):

To a degree which may or may not be useful. You can certainly make it slower - but it's not certain that it will be slow in the same way an inherently slower PC would be, because of many factors pertaining to CPU cache, disk cache, file cache, jittering caused by host OS and competing for resources. Factor in GPU performance and it's the same all over again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works for you, we used the following document from vmware to "build" virtual systems, that are comparable with the hardware we want to test our software on.

We used some Benchmarks from the second section. With that, we create reports on both the hardware and the vmware and build a matrix to compare the systems.

You find the document [here](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/WS6_Performance_Tuning_and_Benchmarking.pdf).

Comment: an interesting document, but it seems to be for benchmarking and improving VM performance. I want to limit the performance of a VM. Did I miss something in there?

Comment: No, I think you get it right. In our project we defined benchmark results for the performance we like to test. We do this by running the benchmark on different hardware, even a very old system. Then we configure different virtual systems so that we match the defined benchmark results. With this methode we duplicate a whole bunch of systems to test our software with different OS and different "Hardware" - configurations. But you had to have realy BIG-System to run more then one VMSystem on one host.

Comment: Thanks, Andreas. It's a useful document.